# Pyspark -- Filter ArrayType rows which contain null value

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am a beginner of PySpark. Suppose I have a Spark dataframe like this:

```
test_df = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame({"a":[[1,2,3], [None,2,3], [None, None, None]]}))
```

Now I hope to filter rows that the array DO NOT contain `None` value (in my case just keep the first row).

I have tried to use:

```
test_df.filter(array_contains(test_df.a, None))
```

But it does not work and throws an error:

> AnalysisException: "cannot resolve 'array_contains(`a`, NULL)' due to
> data type mismatch: Null typed values cannot be used as
> arguments;;\n'Filter array_contains(a#166, null)\n+- LogicalRDD
> [a#166], false\n

How should I filter in the correct way? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`exists`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#exists) function:

```
test_df.filter("!exists(a, x -> x is null)").show() 

#+---------+
#|        a|
#+---------+
#|[1, 2, 3]|
#+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `forall` function.

```
df = test_df.filter(F.expr('forall(a, x -> x is not null)'))
df.show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But my spark version is 2.4.0 and do not have forall function. Is there any alternative way without upgrading the spark version?

Comment: As mentioned by blackbishop, in version 2.4 you can use ```exists```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `aggregate` higher order function to count the number of nulls and filter rows with the count = 0. This will enable you to drop all rows with at least 1 `None` within the array.

```py
data_ls = [
    (1, ["A", "B"]),
    (2, [None, "D"]),
    (3, [None, None])
]

data_sdf = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data_ls).toDF(['a', 'b'])

data_sdf.show()

+---+------+
|  a|     b|
+---+------+
|  1|[A, B]|
|  2| [, D]|
|  3|   [,]|
+---+------+

# count the number of nulls within an array
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('c', func.expr('aggregate(b, 0, (x, y) -> x + int(y is null))')). \
    show()

+---+------+---+
|  a|     b|  c|
+---+------+---+
|  1|[A, B]|  0|
|  2| [, D]|  1|
|  3|   [,]|  2|
+---+------+---+
```

Once you have the column created you can apply the filter as `filter(func.col('c')==0)`.